# Carpet for Tree mulch

Tags: trees, mulch

Will I harm my trees if I put sports field turf around them? Should I keep a certain distance away? Thanks

Comment: This is just not a good idea.  Sports turf will tend to smother the tree as it not as permeable

Comment: What is your goal with the turf? Are you setting up a sports field? Or were you thinking of using it for a weed barrier?

Answer (score 3):

It would probably harm your tree as has been suggested. You can get a great variety of stuff you can mulch with, from broken slate, bark, even glass to use instead. Would it be a thought depending on location to under plant the tree with something like spring bulbs e.g crocus or snowdrops, they prefer to be dry in summer so would cope under the tree. Depending on what type of trees you have.  If they're conifer, not much will grow under them at all, so a bark mulch would be better to allow any rainfall through. Birds like chucking it around though in search of worms and bugs for food. ( I am presuming it's AstroTurf - plastic grass you mean and not sods of turf with a sports grade grass mix that's growing)